# Imitate click of different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently using contactable and triggering the following:

```js
$('#my-contact-div').contactable({
  subject: 'feedback URL:'+location.href,
  header: '',
  url: 'mail.php',
  name: 'Name',
  email: 'Email',
  message : 'Message',
  submit : 'SEND',
  recievedMsg : 'Thank you for your message',
  notRecievedMsg : 'Sorry but your message could not be sent, try again later',
  footer: 'Please feel free to get in touch, we value your feedback',
  hideOnSubmit: true
});
```

However I'd like to be able to slide this form area open when clicking a different div. As the .contactable script runs attached to `#my-contact-div`, would I need to simulate a click on that `div`?

For example on another `div` called `.linkClick` so that when this is clicked, it registers as `#my-contact-div` being clicked.

Comment: `$("#my-contact-div").trigger('click')` would do that, but could be you have to trigger something in that plugin instead

Comment: Sorry, see the updated question.

Comment: Can't you just apply `$("#my-contact-div, .linkClick").contactable({})`?

Comment: No as it attaches the div with the form etc in it. I've sorted it by modding the .js file now.

Comment: You can trigger clicks without plugin with `$("#my-contact-div").click()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it by changing the js file with the following:

```
jQuery('#contactable-inner').toggleClick(function() {
    jQuery('#contactable-overlay').css({display: 'block'});
    jQuery(this).animate({"marginRight": "-=5px"}, "2000");
    jQuery('#contactable-contactForm').animate({"marginRight": "-=0px"}, "2000");
    jQuery(this).animate({"marginRight": "+=387px"}, "4000");
    jQuery('#contactable-contactForm').animate({"marginRight": "+=390px"}, "4000");
}
```

to

```
jQuery('#contactable-inner,.formLink').toggleClick(function() {
    jQuery('#contactable-overlay').css({display: 'block'});
    jQuery('#contactable-inner').animate({"marginRight": "-=5px"}, "2000");
    jQuery('#contactable-contactForm').animate({"marginRight": "-=0px"}, "2000");
    jQuery('#contactable-inner').animate({"marginRight": "+=387px"}, "4000");
    jQuery('#contactable-contactForm').animate({"marginRight": "+=390px"}, "4000");
}
```